# Is there a way to delete the linklist nodes in such a way as to have the head in this piece of code be the only thing left?

Tags: java, linked-list

I have the following code and in the code line where it says 't = obj.deleteNode(obj,3);', I think this should delete 4 and 5. I'm not sure why its not doing it. I also think 'head.next' is Node@788 which is attributed to the number 4. 'head' and 'n' are Node@787 because I passed in the parameter 'obj' which begins with the address Node@787.

```
class Node {
    Node next = null;
    int data;

    public Node(int d) {
        data = d;
        Node next = null;
    }


    Node appendToTail(int d) {
        Node end = new Node(d);
        Node n = this;
        while (n.next != null) {
            n = n.next;
        }
        n.next = end;
        return end;
    }

    Node deleteNode(Node head, int d){
        if(head == null) return null;
        Node n = head;

        if(n.data == d){
            return head.next;
        }

        while(n.next != null){
            if(n.next.data == d){
                n.next = n.next.next;
                return head;
            }
            n = n.next;
        }
        return head;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Node t;
        Node obj = new Node(3);
        t = obj.appendToTail(4);
        t = obj.appendToTail(5);
        t = obj.deleteNode(obj,3);
        for (t = obj; t != null; t = t.next) {
            System.out.println(t.data);
        }

    }
}
```

///

```
Output:

3
4
5
```

///

```
Expected output:

3
```

Comment: Just set the next of Node 3 to null and the rest will be taken care by GarbageCollector. Although I am confused. Deleting a single note isn't same as truncating the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it says `t = obj.deleteNode(obj,3);`, I think this should delete 4 and 5.

No, it shouldn't. Your list is 3→4→5, so deleting the node with 3 should result in 4→5. That is what `deleteNode` is supposed to do: it should find the node that has the given value (3 in this case), and remove only that node, making sure that the preceding node (if any) is rewired to link to the node that follows it (if any).

However, your code has some logical errors:

- You shouldn't reference `obj` after you have deleted that node. It is still there as long as you reference it, but you should only continue with the reference that `deleteNode` returns.
- Don't pass a node reference to the `deleteNode`: the head of the list is supposed to be the instance on which you call `deleteNode`.
- Don't capture the return value of `insertNode` unless you have good reason to use it. This is because it returns the newly *added* node, not (necessarily) the head of the list.
- Use meaningful variable names: replace `t` with `head

Here is how I would code it:

```
class Node {
    Node next = null;
    int data;

    public Node(int d) {
        data = d;
        Node next = null;
    }


    Node appendToTail(int d) {
        Node end = new Node(d);
        Node n = this;
        while (n.next != null) {
            n = n.next;
        }
        n.next = end;
        return end;
    }

    Node deleteNode(int d){ // <-- change parameter list
        Node node = this; // Assume `this` is the head of the list

        if(node.data == d){
            return this.next;
        }

        while(node.next != null){
            if(node.next.data == d){
                node.next = node.next.next;
                return this;
            }
            node = node.next;
        }
        return this;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Node head = new Node(3);
        // Don't assign the return value of appendToTail to a variable.
        //     However, chaining can be useful
        head.appendToTail(4).appendToTail(5);
        // Don't pass a node as argument, but capture the return value
        //     to be the (new) head of the list
        head = head.deleteNode(3); 
        for (Node node = head; node != null; node = node.next) {
            System.out.println(node.data);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are trying to delete node 3 which is head node you are just returning head.next in that case which is stored in 't' but later you are looping through obj which is still pointing to node 3

try this

```
if(n.data == d){
    head = head.next;
    return head;
 }
```

Comment: This makes no difference to what the OP's code has.